# How to apply CSS string using Javascript/jQuery without parsing/tokenizing to retrieve property-value pairs?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have some CSS in string form, *e.g.*

```
border: solid 1px #0000ff; background-color: #ffff00;
```

and I want to apply that CSS to a `<div>`. But all of the examples for using jQuery to apply CSS involve using the `css` method, and to go that route, I'd have to split the CSS string by semicolons (`;`) to retrieve property-value pairs, then by (`:`) to retrieve the property and value, and do

```
$('myDiv').css(property, value);
```

**Is there a way to apply the CSS directly, from its string form?**

I worry that such a naive parsing of the CSS (semicolons and colons) will fail if CSS values can contain those characters, *e.g.* in `url` sub-values.

Comment: you could try using .attr()

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You can retrieve the existing `style` attribute and then set a new one:

```
var target = $("#target");
target.attr("style", target.attr("style") + "; " + yourString);
```

[Live Example](http://jsbin.com/iyijon/1) | [Source](http://jsbin.com/iyijon/1/edit)

Comment: Thanks. I can't believe I didn't think of this in the time I spent typing up that question.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming there are no inline styles set on the element using the `style` attribute, the following will work:

```
$("#foo").attr('style', 'border: solid 1px #0000ff; background-color: #ffff00;');
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/uGYUX/)

Note that this is not an ideal solution though. A much better method would be to put the required styles in a class and use `addClass()` instead.

Comment: You can always just contact the style strings and keep any inline styles.

Comment: @DeclanCook indeed, TJs answer is more complete than mine for that reason

Answer (score 4):

First get your div element using a selector:

```
var div = document.getElementById("myDiv"); // myDiv is the id right?
```

Then get the current css:

```
var css = div.getAttribute("style");
```

If it's `null` then set it to the new style. Otherwise append the new style:

```
var style = 'border: solid 1px #0000ff; background-color: #ffff00;';
if (css === null) css = style;
else css += style;
```

Finally update the style of the div:

```
div.setAttribute("style", css);
```

That's it. See the demo: http://jsfiddle.net/xUWzw/

Answer (score 3):

There is another way of adding string based styles. If below is the style string -

```
    border: solid 1px #0000ff; background-color: #ffff00;
```

Then

```
    var div = document.getElementById('myDiv');
    div.style.cssText = 'border: solid 1px #0000ff; background-color: #ffff00;';
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/eja0zea4/

Answer (score 1):

You can add the css string directly to the div into the style attribute using jQuery .attr() function, but a better way would be to assign a class to your div with jQuery .addClass() function, and adding the css properties to the class.

Answer (score 1):

Just use the jQuery's function  `.attr('style', 'somthing...')`，It's very easy to use and you don't have to think about fault tolerance .

Answer (score 0):

Why not creating a CSS class and just using the addClass removeClass method from [jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/addClass/)

```
.myClass {
   border: solid 1px #0000ff; 
   background-color: #ffff00;
}
```

then

```
$(div).addClass('myClass');
```

Comment: The CSS is entered by the user, after the page loads. Consider, for example, a tutorial page where the user enters bits of CSS, and a target on the page styles dynamically. How would I apply the CSS _class_, then?

Comment: You can post the new user style and create a dynamic CSS file with php script then include it on the fly:

 $('head').append('<link rel="stylesheet" href="style2.css" type="text/css" />');

 or just do everything on client side by injecting inline style:

 $('<style>.newClass { color: red; }</style>').appendTo('body');

Answer (score 0):

you can retrieve it as an object

```
$('myDiv').css({property:"value",property:"value",property:"value"});
```