# apply custom style string to div using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a javascript variable with the following value:

`var style ="border-left:12px solid;border-color:red;position:relative;"`

How can I apply it to a div like below:

```
<div class='my-div'></div>
```

I tried:

`$('.my-div').css({style});`

but failed spectacularly :(

Comment: Because that is not how you make an object

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14829948/how-to-apply-css-string-using-javascript-jquery-without-parsing-tokenizing-to-re

Comment: Read the docs, it's clearly explained how to make the object required. Or go simple and use a class.

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/css/

Comment: Try `$('.my-div').attr('style',style);`

Comment: @RayonDabre: Thank you Rayon, your solution worked...

Answer (score 1):

```
var style = {
    borderLeft:'12px solid',
    borderColor:'red',
    position:'relative'
}
```

The object should look like this. The [CSS](http://api.jquery.com/css/) method takes in an object param. Doing a style string concat will work, but it's ugly.

Or use a class and be simple.

```
$('.my-div').css(style); //append style object to jQuery object
```

Note that using this object notation can also be beneficial because the properties can have logic in them, say for animations, or changing value dependencies.